# "MsalInvalidConfigurationException" in MSAL Flutter

Tags: flutter, azure-ad-msal, msal

The PublicClientApplication is throwing MsalInvalidConfigurationException when running on the first time but it works fine when try to click on the button for the second time to trigger the same code.

This is a function in helper file.

```
Future<String> authAcquireToken() async {
  PublicClientApplication? pca;
  debugPrint("Called Acquiretoken");
  // Create the PCA if not already created
  if (pca == null) {
    debugPrint("Creating PCA...");
    pca = await PublicClientApplication.createPublicClientApplication("clientId",
        authority: "my authority", iosRedirectUri: "uri");
  }
  String res;
  try {
    res = await pca.acquireToken(FFAppState().Scopes);
    Map<String, dynamic> decodedToken = JwtDecoder.decode(res);
    FFAppState().MSALToken = res;
    FFAppState().UserName = decodedToken['name'];
    FFAppState().UserEmail = decodedToken['unique_name'];
    FFAppState().TokenExpr = JwtDecoder.getExpirationDate(res);
    debugPrint("Token Expires: ${FFAppState().TokenExpr}");
    return 'Menu';
  } on MsalUserCancelledException {
    res = "User cancelled";
    debugPrint(res);
  } on MsalNoAccountException {
    res = "no account";
    debugPrint(res);
  } on MsalInvalidConfigurationException {
    res = "invalid config";
    debugPrint(res);
  } on MsalInvalidScopeException {
    res = "Invalid scope";
    debugPrint(res);
  } on MsalException {
    res = "Error getting token. Unspecified reason";
    debugPrint(res);
  }
  return 'LoginPage';
}
```

The button that calls the above functions

```
child: FFButtonWidget(
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        final page = await authAcquireToken();
                                        context.pushNamed('${page}');
                                      },
                                      text: 'Continue with Microsoft',
```

The package used is :-
msal_flutter: ^2.0.1